# Bootstrap stops animation working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-animations

I try to create sidebar component in my web appliaction with simple animation.

```
.sidebar-wrapper {
    /* some styles */
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s ease;
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
```

This is my separated module:

https://jsfiddle.net/pyg1oh5d/7/

Looks fine, but in entire application i use Bootstrap, and then sidebar stops working. What should I change in Bootstrap styles to repair this functionality?

JSfiddle with Bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/pyg1oh5d/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has a `.hidden` class with `display:none;` which is causing the problem.

Just override the `display` for this particular element, or use a different class name:

```
.sidebar-wrapper.hidden {
   display: block !important;
   width: 0;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyg1oh5d/8/)